# How to used the edge detection in opencv python to return number of edge?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

Hi I have the following picture, how to use edge detection to return the result which is equal to 4?

[image]

Here are the original image link:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!An0pWQPDB_ImjGu_nQGSvG3fUBPS

[image]

Comment: please provide link to the original image.

Comment: @krishna hi i have edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your example you are rather looking for corner detection like the Harris algorithm.
Edge detection would match too many edges.

General information on corner detection: [Corner Detection on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection)

And for OpenCV: [Harris Corner Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html)